# Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, boolean

I have a code like this, this is the line 16:

```
$query=mysql_query("select harga from pakaian where 'kodeb'=$kode") or die($query. "<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

$harga=mysql_fetch_row($query);

and when i run it, it showed:

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\orderphp.php on line 16

What's wrong with it? I don't understand

Comment: Also, you have a potential SQL injection vulnerability here, unless you know of course that the $kode variable will always be safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT harga FROM pakaian WHERE kodeb = '$kode'") or die($query. "<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("select harga from pakaian where kodeb='" . $kode . "'") or die ...
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\orderphp.php on line 16 -- means that it's returning **false**, so your query is failing.  Amir has the right answer, but just did not explain what was wrong with your code.